# NetBeans IDE 7.1 icon is not removed even after uninstallation. How do I remove that?

Tags: java, uninstall, netbeans

I installed NetBeans IDE 7.1 in Ubuntu 18.04 using terminal by `sudo sh netbeans...sh` then it was not opening and I wanted to uninstall it. After I removed it using terminal. Still the shortcut exists in activities if I search. I could not find the `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`.
And NetBeans IDE 7.1 exists in Activities Without any icon associated with it.Screenshots attached.

- Netbeans IDE 7.1 in Activities - [image: Netbeans IDE 7.1 in Activities]
- `/usr/share/applications` - [image: /usr/share/applications]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Solution: use `ezame` to find the `.desktop` file:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caldas-lopes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ezame
```

then find its location and delete the `.desktop` file.